# Calling a function on ascx.vb file using hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ascx

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYKn8.pngI want to call a function in ascx.vb file from .ascx page on the click of a link? Please help me. Any Refrence for the same ?

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Edit" onclick="getDemo('abc')"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>


----------------------Server Side -------------------------------
    Function getDemo(ByVal x As String) As Boolean
        Dim c As Int16
        c = 9
    End Function
```

Comment: Client-side and server-side are *entirely separate* things.  Don't think of it as "calling a function".  Think of it as "making a request to the server".  What should that request be?  Are you navigating to a new page (or even reloading the same page)?  Posting a form?  Do you want to do this in the background with AJAX?  What's the experience goal here?

Comment: Reloading the same page @David

Comment: Are you using WebForms then (based on the use of `.ascx.vb`)?  If so, what's stopping you from just putting a `LinkButton` on the page and adding a click event handler to it?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Actually I want to use that linkButton in the Datagrid in each row Named as Edit. Outside it is working fine

Comment: If I use that linkButton inside the grid.It is showing the following error  message @David

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'LinkButton1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: So you've written some specific code to perform a specific task and it is failing in a specific way?  *That* would be a much more meaningful (and helpful to you) Stack Overflow question than the extremely generic one you've posted.  Perhaps you could update the question to include specific information about your attempt and the error you're getting?  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please also see [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David Please look once now, I have added my Code above. Thanks for Support

Comment: Actually On Click of that link, I want to open another Window Whose path I have made as mentioned in code @David

Comment: What is `getDemo`?  In one comment you want to post back to the same page, in another comment you want to open a new window, which is it?  I'm afraid your question is very confusing and unclear.  Please take some time to accurately and specifically describe in the question what you're trying to accomplish and in what specific way the code you've written tries to do that and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @David, Please look now. Hope it explaining well now. I want to call getDemo function on the click of linkbutton in datagrid as above mentioned.Please see the error msg in the link attached above. Thanks

Comment: @david Any Comments please  ?

Comment: A datagrid already has a mechanism for editing, there are tutorials about that. E.g. [Editing Data Within a DataGrid](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/aspnet-cookbook/0596003781/ch01s15.html). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: See my code below. it is rather common to drop in a button, and then have a event (code behind) for that row click. You can use a link, image, or plane jane regular button. See my answer below as to how this is done and works.

Answer (score 1):

I see as noted in comments as to why you can't just drap + drop in the link button (or even a nice regular styled asp.net button (no real reason to use a link button).

And might have been nice to point out that your button is to be in a gridview.

so, you can do it this way:

So, drop in a gridview - let wizard built it. Now blow out the data source on the page (don't need). Drag + drop a plane jane asp.net button onto the page (drop it outside of the gv). Now move the button inside the GV.

We now have this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
                            CssClass="btn"
                            />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, now our code to load the grid, looks like this:
(always, but always always check the ispostback = false - first page grid load).

So, we have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels Order by HoteName", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData as DataTable = New Datatable()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Ok, and now we see/have this:

[image]

Ok, so now lets wire up the button click. It is JUST a plane jane asp.net button.

So we can't double click on the button to create the event stub for the button (its inside of the GV).

So, in the markup, start typing the event name in like this:

[image]

Note VERY close, you get a intel-sense dialog. In that above dialog, choose create new event. It will "seem" like nothing occured. We now see/have this:

```
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
                            CssClass="btn"
                            OnClick="cmdRow_Click"
                            />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, if we flip to code behind, you see the code event has been wired up for you. So, on that row click, lets get that row.

```
Protected Sub cmdRow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender

    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.Parent.Parent

    Debug.Print("row index click = " & gRow.RowIndex)

    Dim intPKID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Debug.Print("PK row ID = " & intPKID)

    ' get the hotel name (cell 2)
    Debug.Print("Hotel name click = " & gRow.Cells(2).Text)

End Sub
```

So you are 100% free to drop in a button, or link button (not really sure why you would use a link buttion here).

The "trick" or issue is how to wire up the click event - you have to type in the markup, since as noted, you can't just click on the button to create a event in the code behind, since it is inside of a grid.

but, as per above, you can still create the event by typing in the markup.

At that point, you have a regular plane jane button, and as the click event shows, you can grab the current GridViewRow by using btn.Parent.Parent.

At that point, you have all the information about that row - row index, the primary key.

NOTE VERY careful in above how I did NOT have to expose the PK id. I did not hide the row, or even EVER expose the database PK id's in that GV.

This nice feature is how/why the DataKeys setting exists. It lets you use/have/get/enjoy use of the database row PK's in the GV, but NOT have to ever expose the PK 's client side, nor do you even have to render the PK row id's in the GV. So, note how I setup DataKeys="ID". That's is a great feature since as noted, you can now use + enjoy and get the PK database ID, but NOT have to display, include, or even show or include the PK's in the GV. Needless to say, that is a great security feature, since in most cases one should not display nor include the database ID's in the client side (it is a big security risk).

The above process will work the same if you drop in a link button, but I can't see why you would when a plane jane regular button can (and should) be used here.

And you can do the same with a image button, or whatever you want. The main concept here is HOW to create the click event, and then in that code you can see how easy it is to get the grid view row.

Once you have the row, then you can get cells/values, or even as noted the row index. And with row index, then you can get the nice and wonderful database PK id that was not exposed anywhere in the client side GV.

Comment: Thank you! Great tutorial. That DataKeys is new to me and will be very handy.

Comment: I didn't know I could use a DataReader as a DataSource for a GridView. That is a revelation. However, I would add a Using block for the reader.

Comment: In my quest to optimize code - I want less and less. However, I just edited that code. There are two good reasons to NOT use this shortcut. #1: If you add a datapager, it will not work. #2: Few people realize that during the data bind event (and only during), the row data bound event has FULL use of the data source row used to bind that row. Thus, for formatting, maybe a tax calc, etc you have use of all data columns (not just ones in the grid). A quick shortcut, but it don't work with data pager, or grabbing the data source row during row data bind event. I thus edited code to remove reader.